Next.js Image sometimes fails to load in production
I have a Next.js project (version 14 with the app directory) and I am having an issue where in production the images from the public folder that I load using the Image component fail to load sometimes but other times they load fine. I am not sure why that is happening. I have also installed the sharp module as suggested by Next.js which apparently helps with image optimization.
Here is how I have my images:
import Image from 'next/image';

export default async function Header() {
  return (
      <header className={styles.header}>
        <div className="container">
          <Image src={'/assets/i/img-logo.png'} width={140} height={53} alt={'Company Name'} />
        </div>
      </header>
  );
}

In the public folder I have the following structure:
public -> assets -> i -> img-logo.png

I also tried importing the image like import logo from '../public/assets/i/img-logo.png' and using logo as the source for the Image component but I face the same problem where the image loads sometimes but others it doesn't. When it doesn't loads it is like the request "hangs" and then just timeout. But when it does loads it is quite quick with no long loading time.
Any help is appreciated.

Are you seeing any relevant messages in your developer console when you observe this behavior?

@esqew I just tried now and got it to not load and image requests stay on "pending" on the network tab for a while and after some time in the request response it shows an nginix 504 Gateway Time-out
